# How to do AngularJS research dom?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

How to do AngularJS research dom?

I have a HTML that i'm inserting with jquery method `.html()`, and inside this html i have a directive. How can i do this work?

Example:

`//This directive should show a alert
<div alert-directive></div>`

i'm inserting the above html in my container with `$(".container").html('<div alert-directive></div>')`. The directive does not execute.

Comment: Could you please give some more details over the scenario. Thx

Comment: provide a demo please

Comment: If you need to use jQuery to do something like this with AngularJS, 9 out of 10 times, you're doing it wrong. Try to describe _what_ you're trying to accomplish, don't describe your failed approach. It can probably be done without jQuery.

Comment: the jquery is just to exemplify what i'm trying to do. Erti-Chris Eelmaa and Luca has answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do something similiar in my hobby project, here is a copy paste that should help you:

```
  var html = '<div bindonce="result" class="searchResult newResult" ' +
                            'ng-click = "clicky(result)" ' +
                            'bo-id = "result.id"' + 
                            'ng-mouseenter = "hover = true"' +
                            'ng-mouseleave = "hover = false"' +
                            'ng-include src="\'views/partial/search_result.html\'">' +
                            '</div>';

                        // extending current scope
                        var newScope = scope.$new();
                        newScope.result = item;

                        var compiledHtml = $compile(html)(newScope);
                        $("#searchResults").append(compiledHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to acknowledge AngularJs of your insertion. In order to do that first you have to inject your controller with the $compile service ...

```
yourOwnApp.controller('exampleCtrl', ['$scope','$compile', function($scope, $compile) {

your controller code here ...

}]);
```

... then inside your controller compile your html markup and insert into the DOM:

```
var htmlTemplate = '<div alert-directive></div>';
var newElement = $compile(htmlTemplate)($scope);

$(".container").append(newElement);
```

Hope it helps.

Cheers, Luca

Comment: Thanks Luca Anceschi.

Comment: @LucaAnceschi Not the downvoter, but probably because your solution doesn't address the fact that what he's trying to do is most likely wrong. As I also commented on the question, when you need to use jQuery with AngularJS, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @kba: you may be right on the philosophy of the relationship of the two libraries. I thought about it myself, yet the question itself should have been put on hold or downvoted. Cheers

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the question. Sometimes, the asker just thinks the solution lies elsewhere. When a user says: I'm trying to accomplish X, so I did Y, but now I have problem Z, the solution isn't always to solve problem Z, but instead suggest a better Y.